# Select a value from the drop-down list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to choose a value from the drop-down list? I using Selenium on Python.
Here is a short page code:

```
<label for="input_registration_data:account_region">Регион:</label>
<select id="input_registration_data:account_region" name="input_registration_data:account_region" class="search_select hasChosen" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,0)" data-live-search="true" data-dropupauto="false" data-container="body" style="outline: rgb(83, 129, 172) none 0px;">  
    <option value="01">01 - Респ Адыгея</option>
    <option value="78" selected="selected">78 - Санкт-Петербург г</option>
    <option value="79">79 - Еврейская ао</option>
    <option value="83">83 - Ненецкий ао</option>
    <option value="86">86 - Ханты-мансийский ао</option>
    <option value="87">87 - Чукотский ао</option>
    <option value="89">89 - Ямало-ненецкий ао</option>
    <option value="91">91 - Респ Крым</option>
    <option value="92">92 - Севастополь г</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
s2 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('input_registration_data:account_region'))
s2.select_by_value("83")
```

but nothing happens. Which method is most suitable for this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _but nothing happens._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
s2 = Select(browser.find_element_css_selector(".search_select.hasChosen"))
s2.select_by_value("83")
```

PS: There are several HTML elements with `id` like `input_registration_data:account_region`.

I hope it helps you!